# How to handle different date time formats using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I have a String with a datetime format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

I use this in my source code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"%e. %B %Y"];
NSString *test = [formatter stringFromDate:@"2010-01-10 13:55:15"];
```

I want to convert from "2010-01-10 13:55:15" to "10. January 2010".
But my implementation does not work.

What's wrong here?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Updated source code:

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"];
NSString *test1 = [formatter stringFromDate:@"2010-01-10 13:55:15"];

NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"%d. %M4 %Y"];
NSString *test2 = [formatter1 stringFromDate:test1];
```

Comment: pueden ayudarme con estan pregunta 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162835/how-to-use-nsdateformatter-to-venezuela

gracias

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A date formatter can only handle one format at a time. You need to take this approach:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"2010-01-10 13:55:15"];

NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setDateFormat:@"d. MMMM YYYY"];
NSString *s = [f2 stringFromDate:date];
```

s will now be "10. January 2010"

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few examples of working with data formatters from my code. You should be able to take any one of these functions and tweak it for your format.

USAGE

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [Constants getTitleDateFormatter];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];        
[dateFormatter release];
```

FUNCTIONS

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) getDateFormatterWithTimeZone {
  //Returns the following information in the format of the locale:
  //YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z (Z is time zone)
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
  [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
  [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
  return dateFormatter;
```

}

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatterWithoutYear {
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [Constants getDateFormatterWithTimeZone];
  [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
  NSString *format = [dateFormatter dateFormat];
  format = [format stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/yy" withString:@""];
  NSRange secondSpace;
  secondSpace.location = format.length-2;
  secondSpace.length = 1;
  format = [format stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:secondSpace withString:@""];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
  return dateFormatter;
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *) dateFormatterMonthDayOnly {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [Constants getDateFormatterWithTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *format = [dateFormatter dateFormat];
    format = [format stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/yy" withString:@""];
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 3;
    format = [format substringWithRange:range];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    return dateFormatter;
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *) getTitleDateFormatter {
    //Returns the following information in the format of the locale:
    //MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ssa
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [Constants getDateFormatterWithTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *format = [dateFormatter dateFormat];
    NSRange secondSpace;
    secondSpace.location = format.length-2;
    secondSpace.length = 1;
    format = [format stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"-"];
    format = [format stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:secondSpace withString:@""];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];   
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, make sure you set the behavior to 10.4 - more modern, works better in my experience.

```
[dateTimeFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
```

Next, you can't use the same format to parse and format if they have 2 different string representations, so use 2 formatters, or change the string format between parsing and then formatting.

Also make sure you consider the formatting options:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

lowercase is e is the day of week, lowercase d is the day of the month.

For month, use MMMM, not B.

Comment: Hm, I think I do not understand the "system". I updated my first post. I do not know why this won't work.

Comment: Had a typo - by M4, I meant 4 Ms, as in MMMM - whoops.

Comment: setFormatterBehavior: isn't required on iPhone OS, it *only* operates in the 10.4+ mode.

Comment: good call - but all the more reason he should be using the 10.4 mode formatting syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`[NSFormatter dateFromString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:) to convert your string-based date to an `NSDate` instance. From there you want to use `stringFromDate` with the `NSDate`, not the string as you have written above. I'm not sure about using the same NSDateFormatter for both parsing and formatting - you may need two separate instances to handle the different format styles.

Comment: You mean NSDateFormatter? I think these methods are not available in iPhone only Mac OS X. You also link to the Mac OS X reference library.

Comment: The routines I reference are available for the iPhone, too. Glad you found your answer all the same.