# Seconds to - Minutes - Hours - Milliseconds

Tags: ios, nstimer

I'm using the NSTimer, with this code:

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

    MainInt = 0;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

How can I display milliseconds and minutes also?

Didn't find any simple yet working method.

Answer (score 1):

For milliseconds use:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

For minutes use:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Is it reasonable to use an NSTimer object that has a time interval of one millisecond? Do you know of any documentation that discusses this?

Comment: If you try this with one millisecond intervals it will most likely miss quite a few beats. However, do you really need such minuscule intervals? If you refresh the display every 50 milliseconds the user will not be able to tell the difference. (If you want the display to have digits other than zero, then simply use an odd interval, like 53 milliseconds.)

Comment: I was just interested in the possibility, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Make a shorter interval, like 0.1f 
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f `target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`
 and use `NSDateFormatter` to display the counter. An example for the `NSDateFormatter` can be found here: timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

How the NSDateFormatter works is explained very well here: [How to handle different date time formats using NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035201/iphone-nsdateformatter)

Your timer should update a float variable where it stores the milliseconds.

Sample:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss:SSS"];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]*-1;
    NSString *clock = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:startDate]];
```

But you should go Roy Sharon answer.

Comment: Can you explain NSDateFormatter a bit more?

Comment: Can you please give an example?