# How to implement a laps feature to a stopwatch app

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer

I am trying to implement a way to where the user taps the **Lap** button, it copies the value of the text from the stopwatch label. Every time the user presses the button, they get the elapsed value from the last time that the button was pressed. Does anybody know how to implement such a feature.

```
-(IBAction) lapButtonPressed {
self.lapLabel.text = self.timeLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: 1. Get current text of time label. 2. Store it somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add milliseconds to a stopwatch app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792042/how-to-add-milliseconds-to-a-stopwatch-app)

Comment: @mohacs No, this is not a duplicate of all at that

Comment: You asked same question yesterday and yes it is pretty much same, just some values are different, why don't you try to update your previous question?

Comment: You don't appear to have an actual issue; why don't you try to implement this yourself and then post a question when you have a problem you cannot solve.

Comment: The issue is, I don't understand how I can do this, that why I am asking how to do it.....

Comment: What don't you understand about it exactly? How to get the value? How to display the value? You're being very generic.

Comment: I don't understand how to get the value and and display the value.

Comment: Disregard this comment

Comment: @AdamPro13. What do I put under that

Answer (score 0):

Think about it.

- When do you copy the value? When the lap button is pressed.
- Where is the time value stored? In the time label.
- How to you get the time in the lap label? Set the text equal to the time label.

`- (IBAction)lapButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
   self.lapLabel.text = self.timeLabel.text;
}`