# Not able to get date from string\

Tags: iphone, ios

I am just use below code to convert the string into date.
Code is working perfect, But sometimes it will not return the date.
Any idea ??

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate  = [[NSDate alloc] init];
myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strTime];
```

Thanks,

Comment: refer this link [NSDateFormatter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035201/iphone-nsdateformatter

Comment: your code is working fine i test it pass strTime = @"1012/11/08 15:30:20" so its give you proper output.

Comment: @Priyanka: its also at my end, but sometime its not returning value. I am not able to get why its not returning value.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh when your string format is not same as string value your passing for convert to date is not match then your date value is nil.

Comment: @Priyanka: Nupp, string is same as "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" this format, and still i am not able to it :(

Comment: @Nirmalsinh, this link <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html> help you?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to convert string to date just use bellow method with your string format

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date {
     NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]; // use formate of date which you got in string date..
    // NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", date);
     date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
    nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
    return nowDate;
}
```