# NSDateFormatter.dateFromString is returning (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am using `NSDateFormatter` for the first time , when i try to get date from string then it's giving `nil`.

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd , YYYY"];    
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];    
NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-10 09:51:24 +0000"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

please tell what i am missing here , thanks in advance . . .

Comment: the format and string are not matched

Comment: k , thanks i will change the format and give it a try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035201/how-to-handle-different-date-time-formats-using-nsdateformatter use this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-10 09:51:24 +0000"];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd , YYYY"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSDate *outDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",date,dateString,outDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... It may help you

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];

    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-10 09:51:24 +0000"];

    NSLog(@"%@",date);  // prints 2013-10-10 09:51:24 +0000

 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd , YYYY"];

NSString *String = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSDate *final = [formatter dateFromString:String];

NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",date,String,final);
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you?